# Fork/Join calculation

Tags: groovy, fork-join, gpars

I have this example of a fork/join calculation. Could somebody please describe me shortly how it works here?

```
def quicksortForkJoin(numbers) {
    withPool {
        runForkJoin(0, numbers) {index, list ->
            def groups = list.groupBy {it <=> list[list.size().intdiv(2)]}
            if ((list.size() < 2) || (groups.size() == 1)) {
                return [index: index, list: list.clone()]
            }
            (-1..1).each { forkOffChild(it, groups[it] ?: [])}
            return [index: index, list: childrenResults.sort {it.index}.sum {it.list}]
        }.list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any good?

```
def quicksortForkJoin(numbers) {

    // Create a pool of workers the default size
    withPool {

        // Run a fork with index 0 and the numbers
        runForkJoin(0, numbers) {index, list ->         // [1]

            // Split numbers into 3 groups:
            //    -1: those less than the "middle" number
            //     0: those equal to the "middle" number
            //     1: those greater than the "middle" number
            def groups = list.groupBy {it <=> list[list.size().intdiv(2)]}

            // If there are less than 2 numbers to sort, or all numbers are equal
            if ((list.size() < 2) || (groups.size() == 1)) {

                // return the index and a clone of the current list
                return [index: index, list: list.clone()]
            }

            // Otherwise, fork off a child process for each of the
            // groups above (less than, equal and greater than)
            // forkOffChild will not block, and will effectively go back
            // to line [1] with the new index and list
            (-1..1).each { forkOffChild(it, groups[it] ?: [])}

            // Block waiting for all 3 children to finish, then sort the
            // results so the indexes are [ -1, 0, 1 ] and then join the
            // lists of numbers back together 
            return [ index: index,
                     list: childrenResults.sort {it.index}.sum {it.list}]

            // when done, return the `list` property from the final map
        }.list
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I still don't understand the part with `groups`: How is it split into 3 groups? This line `{it <=> list[list.size().intdiv(2)]}` is quite confusing.

Comment: @user1170330 `list[list.size().intdiv(2)]` gets the "middle" element, ie for: `[ 3, 6, 4, 3, 1 ]` it will give you the number `4`.  So let's call this `mid`.  The group closure then becomes `{ it <=> mid }`.  The spaceship operator basically does a `compare` between the two elements and returns `-1`, `0` or `1`.  So the `groupBy` takes every element in the list, and returns a map with 3 keys like so (for the example list in this comment) `[ -1:[3, 3, 1], 0:[4], 1:[6] ]`